# Remove 'Search the web' / 'Search with Google' service

Tags: safari, services, root, contextual-menu

How would you remove 'Search with Google' from the right-click menu? The setting in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** has no effect at all. Uninstalling Safari just turns 'Search with Google' into 'Search the Web'.

PS: Yes, I am aware that the answer most likely will involve disabling SIP and changing/deleting system files. I still want to know, please.

This is on macOS Big Sur.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: I am trying to achive, that my system isn't full of services I do not use. I have no intention of ever using safari, and having a permanent entry in the right-click menu bothers me. Especially since there is a supposed setting to disable it, but it doesn't work. I managed to remove iMessage from the share menu and the permanent notification if you do not use iCloud. This is the last thing on my list.

Comment: @MattSephton - It actually appears in any text-aware app [including Chrome], even in Finder if you're editing a file name. Which specific search engine is controlled by a Safari pref. Presumably removing Safari whilst having it still selected just breaks the association, but not the menu item itself.